# how to remove last merged commit's work in master branch with a merge request created

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

we have some temp work merged into master branch (last commit). Now, we need to roll it back. But obviously, I don't have the power to directly make changes on master. And we always need to create merge request for review.
I created a feature branch from the 2nd last commit of the master branch. However, when I tried to create a merge request, GitLab does NOT recognize any changes. Any easy way I can achieve this beside I manually remove the previous changes ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this was done on your local `master` branch only, then you can undo that latest commit, keeping all the changes.

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit/

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

> Reset will rewind your current HEAD branch to the specified revision. In our example above, we'd like to return to the one before the current revision - effectively making our last commit undone.
>
> Note the `--soft` flag: this makes sure that the changes in undone revisions are preserved. After running the command, you'll find the changes as uncommitted local modifications in your working copy.

Once you revert this commit:

1. Create a new branch
2. Commit these changes to that branch
3. Push that branch to your repo
4. Create a pull request

Comment: sorry, i didn't make it clear. The change we want to roll back has already merged into remote master branch.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to *remove* commits from a branch using a Merge Request. You would need to remove them locally and then force push. This is typically frowned upon for shared branches such as `master`, and as you point out you don't even have permission to push to `master`, let alone *force* push.

Instead, you can revert the commit(s) you wish to undo. Since the commit is the top commit on your branch it's simply:

```
git revert HEAD
```

The `revert` command creates a new commit which is the opposite of the commit to revert. Now push this new commit and create your MR to merge that branch into `master`.

**Side Note:** the reason what you tried didn't work, and showed no changes, is because your branch was one commit behind `master`. There were no *new* commit IDs on your branch that weren't yet on `master` so there was nothing to merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create a git revert pull request by clicking on `revert` in gitlab webpage. Almost every code platform has that feature, after clicked that revert gitlab will generate a PR to the last commit.

In the pull request, you can explain why you are trying to revert a bad commit in description zone. This is a fast way without playing with git command.

[Url link to gitlab revert a bad commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RtDg.png)